# find sentence among sentence of words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, named-entity-recognition

I have two Pandas data frames. One where all the sentences are split by words vertically and look like this

```
Sentence | Text   
1            I
1          like
1          Cats
2          The
2          man
2         plays
2         soccer
2         today
```

And the other data frame looks like this:

```
ID      | Text         | Tags
1         plays soccer   sport
2          man           human
3         like cats     interest
```

What I would like is to map the Tags to the first data frame for the words in the sentence that match both places, and those who does not match get an "O" to symbolize it.

```
Sentence | Text        | Tags 
1          I             O
1          like          interest
1          Cats          interest
2          The           O
2          man           human
2          plays         sport
2          soccer        sport
2          today         O
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `df1` is your first table and `df2` is your second (where `ID` is the index) then you can:

- Explode your second table (`str.split()` + `explode()`)
- `merge()` with a left join
- `fillna()` the `NaN` with `O`

E.g.:

```
In []:
df1.merge(df2.assign(Text=df2.Text.str.split()).explode('Text'), 'left').fillna('O')

Out[]:
   Sentence    Text      Tags
0         1       I         O
1         1    like  interest
2         1    Cats         O
3         2     The         O
4         2     man     human
5         2   plays     sport
6         2  soccer     sport
7         2   today         O
```

This is currently case sensitive but it is an easy exercise to merge on a column that is `str.lower()` of `Text`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, if I have the same word in a sentence, let's say "man". The first Tag is human, but in another the Tag it might be sapiens. Do you have any proposal to how one should treat this ambiguity? Could you keep the one, where the tag is used most times? If so, can you propose how to write that code?